# How can I use ElementRef instead of document.getElementById to fetch the nodeList

Tags: angular, checkbox, nodelist, elementref

Currently I am using `document.getElementById` to fetch the exact checkbox that needs to be checked.

Here is the code:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    this.tradeids = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('tradeids'));                                     
    var x;          
    for (let objtrade of this.tradeids) {
        x = document.getElementById(objtrade);
        x.checked = true;
    }

    this.programIds = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('programIds'));
    var y;
    for (let objprogram of this.programIds) {
        x = document.getElementById(objprogram);
        x.checked = true;
    }
}, 100);
```

}

How can I replace `document.getElementbyId` with `elementRef` or any other typescript function.

FYI,
I did use `elementRef` using `querySelector` but the log says that `nativeElement` is undefined.

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/how-can-i-select-an-element-in-a-component-template) follow this for `elementRef` i thing you need to also go through with `typescript`. last one is why you are using querySelector for checkbox other way is there like template-driven or rectiveForm according to me.

Comment: I tried this but i am not able to get the nodeList. NativeElement is undefined